# copy mysql data from old xampp to new

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

i was forced to change my laptop, i saved my sql data folder and htdocs datas 
then install xampp in my new laptop and copy my database folder and htdocs from old xampp to new xampp
my localhost can't shows my website and change the page to wordpress installation and when i complete the installation show errors like this photos 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuTG4.png)

i copy ibdata1 from old to new but it didn't work
my life depends on this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do the restore thing by :

1. Copy your wordpress source to your new htdocs folder
2. Login the phpmyadmin of your old laptop then select the old database,backup it to a sql file;

   Please note that to tick the important steps:

   "Export method:  Custom - display all possible options "

   "Object creation options"

   ```
   Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement, 
   Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement
   IF NOT EXISTS (less efficient as indexes will be generated during table creation)
   Truncate table before insert
   ```
3. Login the phpmyadmin of your new laptop then import the sql file.
4. Go to the wp-config.php to set your database user account and password.
5. If you run it in the remote server, please check wp_options to update the correct site_url or home.